# shell script which creates different file for each SQL query

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

my file contains multiple SQL queries separated by ;I want a script which creates different file for each SQL query

Comment: So, where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: Congratulations! And welcome to SO. Would love to help!

Please [read this guide for asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: try the csplit unix command

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. On this site you will find professional programmers and programming enthusiasts who are willing to help you, but you should do some effort yourself first.

I will give you a head start to the solution of your question. Try the following code in a new/empty directory and see what it does ;-)

```
$ myfile=tmp.log
$ echo 'insert into bla where x=1; select * from derp; delete * from * where 1=1;' > $myfile
$ while read -d ';' query; do echo $query >> `echo $query | md5sum | grep -Eo '^[^ ]*'`.sql ; done < $myfile
$ for i in *sql; do echo -n "$i: "; cat $i; done
397ef94bdde1d41e546ad00cd0ca0e20.sql:  delete * from * where 1=1
cdd2e2af0889c51ab9dc3be7b2a359e2.sql:  select * from derp
e617194b23b1cac13bd8c743fb38f84c.sql: insert into bla where x=1
```

**EDIT: Explanation:**

This line reads line by line, delimited by `-d ':'`, from `$myfile` and echoes the query `$query` to the screen: 
`while read -d ';' query; do echo $query ; done < $myfile`

The body of the loop generates an file with the content of `$query`. I didn't know how you wanted to name every file, thus I've taken the liberty to name the file as `md5sum` of the query. `grep` and is only there to remove a small part of the `md5sum` string. 
`` echo $query >> `echo $query | md5sum | grep -Eo '^[^ ]*'`.sql ``

Everything wrapped with a `` ` `` is executed first and the data returning from that command is used, but `$()` is also used. Example:

```
$ ls `echo $HOME`
$ ls $(echo $HOME)
```

Comment: i am new to Shell scripting, would you explain me the code here, Thank You

Comment: No problem. Do you understand the explanation?